# Connecting 2 Arduinos with Bluetooth

Tags: arduino, communication, bluetooth, transceiver

I have been looking on Google for a project that involves 2 Arduinos communicating with Bluetooth. The only examples I can find are with an Arduino to an **Android** phone.

Does anyone have links to let me know how I would go about hooking two Arduinos up to Bluetooth?

The Bluetooth module I'm using is the Bluetooth RF Transceiver Module Card RS232 TTL (i guess better known as the HC-05). [Here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30ft-3-3VDC-Mini-Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-Card-RS232-TTL-Antenna-/310643697340?pt=US_USB_Bluetooth_Adapters_Dongles&hash=item4853cea6bc) is an ebay link.

Comment: When you say "communicating" what exactly are the 2 Arduinos going to share? If it is serial data, RX/TX to TX/RX on the BT; each. Then Serial.read() and Serial.write() to exchange data streams. To exchange pin outputs is a different story.

Comment: You can use AT command to do it